# Runnig docker as nonRoot with --user $(id -u) cant create /var/lib/

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grafana, user-permissions

Hello im fairly new to docker and i am trying to get influxdb and grafana up and running.

I already went through some problem solving and want to get you on the same page with a little summary.

1. Got a docker-compose file from [here](https://github.com/jkehres/docker-compose-influxdb-grafana)
2. did sudo docker-compose up -d
3. ran into the problem, that arguments like INFLUXDB_DB=db0 insdide the docker-compose.yml are not applied by the containers. So the databaes db0 wasnt created for example.
4. changes to the containers though would persist. So i could create a database and after a restart it was still there
5. tested each container as standalone with docker run
6. figured out if I used bind mount instead of docker volumes it worked for influxdb
7. the grafana container wouldn't start

```sh
sudo docker run --volume "$PWD/data:/var/lib/grafana" -p 3000:3000 grafana/grafana:latest
GF_PATHS_DATA='/var/lib/grafana' is not writable.
You may have issues with file permissions, more information here: http://docs.grafana.org/installation/docker/#migration-from-a-previous-version-of-the-docker-container-to-5-1-or-later
mkdir: can't create directory '/var/lib/grafana/plugins': Permission denied
```

8. read [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/configure-docker/) that I need do define a user with `$(id -u)` if I want to use bind mount with grafana
9. did that, but then the user has no permission to create the */var/lib/grafana* directory

```sh
 sudo docker run --user $(id -u) --volume "$PWD/data:/var/lib/grafana" -p 3000:3000 grafana/grafana:latest
GF_PATHS_DATA='/var/lib/grafana' is not writable.
You may have issues with file permissions, more information here: http://docs.grafana.org/installation/docker/#migration-from-a-previous-version-of-the-docker-container-to-5-1-or-later
mkdir: can't create directory '/var/lib/grafana/plugins': Permission denied
```

10. when i set the --user argument to root with 0:0 it works but i read some best practices where running as root for testing is ok but for production it would be not ideal.
11. i also read that i can add a user to the docker group to give the user the permissions
12. there was no docker group on my system so i read [here](https://coderleaf.wordpress.com/2017/02/10/run-docker-as-user-on-centos7/), that i can create one and then adding the docker.socket to that group via /etc/docker/daemon.json but that file doesnt exist and i cant create it and i think i am pretty deep down the rabbit hole to just stop and ask if i am on the wrong path and did something wrong.

How can i start the containers as nonRoot without giving them to much permissions is my main question i think.

using:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by running the container as root, `chown` the data dir and then `su` to grafana user. In docker-compose, this looks like:

```
grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:8.2.3
    volumes:
        - ./data/grafana:/var/lib/grafana
    user: root
    entrypoint:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - |
          chown grafana /var/lib/grafana
          exec su grafana -s /bin/sh -c /run.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember dealing with similar issues long ago.

I recommend

one time

```
mkdir data/grafana
```

and then

```
sudo docker run --volume "$PWD/data:/var/lib" -p 3000:3000 grafana/grafana:latest
```

because as I recall whenever you volume mount something it mounts as owned by root.  There is no way to change the ownership of the mounted volume.

But you can change the ownership of files and directories inside the mounted volume and they do not have to be root.

So in my solution you are just mounting data to /var/lib, /var/lib will be owned by root but /var/lib/grafana will be owned by a regular user.

This would obviously hide the contents of any other folders in the /var/lib directory but maybe there is not anything important there.  If there is then could you configure the program to look for /var/lib/grafana at some other location.  For example /srv/grafana then change the invocation to

```
sudo docker run --env GRAFANA_DIR=/srv/grafana --volume "$PWD/data:/srv" -p 3000:3000 grafana/grafana:latest
```

Lastly, I do not see why it would be a security issue to run as root.
That is something I am not sure I agree with.

Comment: Hey, thanks for reading throug. The issue with the bind mount on the host owned by root is not really the problem. It IS a problem but none of my concern right now. My problem ist, that the folder inside the container /var/lib/grafana which is assume will be created by a script inside the container cant be created because of permission issues. So Something wrong with the user inside the container i think.

Comment: I really dont understand enough about docker to know why running as root can be a security issue but i assume that the problem is that when the user inside the container is root and your image may have some secuity issue, than someon could do stuff inside the container which would not be intended. And i think starting with sudo docker... runs the user inside the container as root automaticly unless declared other with the --user argument

Comment: @SebastianScholz You have multiple questions.  I think you can create a "docker" group.  Then add your user to that group.  Then reboot your computer.  Aftwards you should be able to invoke docker with `docker` and not need `sudo docker` but that is a small thing unrelated to the main point of your question.

Comment: @SebastianScholz I think the thing wrong with the user inside the container is that it does not have write permissions on "/var/lib/grafana" because only root has write permissions on that directory.  For diagnostic purposes can you run `sudo docker run --user $(id -u) --volume "$PWD/data:/var/lib/grafana" -p 3000:3000 grafana/grafana:latest stat /var/lib/grafana`.  This will tell you exactly what the permissions are.

Comment: @SebastianScholz Speaking in generalities it is not a security problem to run a container as root.  If you run as a regular user and some hacker breaks your application they will have access to whatever a regular user has access to.  If you run as root and some hacker breaks your application they will have access to the entire container.  It sounds like running as a regular user is safer; but in practice there is nothing important on the container that the regular user does not have access to.  Hopefully the hacker does not figure out how to break out of the container

Comment: @SebastianScholz However, it is theoretically possible that it might make a difference and some programs will just not work as root - so learning how to run a container as a regular user is a useful skill - but not in my opinion security critical.